# Where does Liferea stores user data?

Tags: liferea

On which folder(s) Liferea stores user data (subscriptions and articles)? There is a folder named `.liferea_1.8` in my home but it does not contain any user data.

The goal is to synchronise that folder with a cloud service so that Liferea accesses the exact same assets at home, work, etc.

Note: the official Liferea support medium, a [mailling list](http://sourceforge.net/p/liferea/mailman/liferea-devel/), seems to have been deactivated last April.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configuration files mainly founded under `~/.gconf/apps/liferea` While other files such as user data and subscriptions,etc... are founded in a SQLite3 database named liferea.db under `~/.liferea_1.8` directory.

[image]

If you open that db you can find the data inside:

[image]

Comment: it's in .local I now

Answer (score 0):

Feed metadata such as URLs and update intervals are in "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/liferea". Feed articles are in "$XDG_DATA_HOME/liferea". (See [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html) for the explanation of the variables.)